# fetch no of rows from table 2 with id of table 1

Tags: mysql

I have some thing to do here with subquery but I am not able to do.
I want the result from a table with a extra field to show to no of results from other table with a column value from table 1.
table1:

```
CountryId   Country  ISO2   ISO3
```

table2:

```
id     noof_country    state
```

I have to retrive noof_country count in table 1 as count field

**EDIT**
my actual tables are

table 1:
ad_id   job_country status  delete  days_left

table 2:
CountryId   Country ISO2    status

I have done query in two phase:

```
$sql_map = "select distinct c.ISO2, c.Country, a.job_country
    from rec_countries c, rec_advert a
    where c.status = 1
    and DATE(a.modified_date) >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY
    and c.ISO2 <> '--'
    and c.ISO2 <> ''
    and c.CountryId = a.job_country
    and a.status = 1
    and a.`delete` = 0
    and a.days_left >0
    ";
$res = mysql_query($sql_map);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)){
    $jobs_no = count($row['job_country']);
    $sql_job = "SELECT COUNT( job_country ) AS jobs_no
    FROM rec_advert
    WHERE job_country = ".$row['job_country']."
    and status = 1
    and `delete` = 0
    and days_left >0";
    $resjob=mysql_query($sql_job);
    $rowjob = mysql_fetch_array($resjob);

    //here jobs_no is the count of total rows
}
```

Here I want to do with subquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I read the question right, this should work:

```
SELECT
    CountryId,
    Country,
    ISO2,
    ISO3,
    (
        SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT noof_country)
        FROM table2
        WHERE table2.id = table1.CountryId
    ) AS noof_country_count
FROM table1
```

It's not immediately clear in your question which column in `table1` is a foreign key to which column in `table2`... or if they are even related that way.  If this query doesn't work for you, please clarify your schema.

---

Based on your updated information, try this:

```
select distinct c.ISO2, c.Country, a.job_country,
    (
        select COUNT(a2.job_country)
        from rec_advert a2
        where a2.job_country = a.job_country
        and a2.status = 1
        and a2.`delete` = 0
        and a2.days_left >0
    ) as jobs_no
    from rec_countries c, rec_advert a
    where c.status = 1
    and DATE(a.modified_date) >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY
    and c.ISO2 <> '--'
    and c.ISO2 <> ''
    and c.CountryId = a.job_country
    and a.status = 1
    and a.`delete` = 0
    and a.days_left >0
```